# Categorize array by date using moment.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, momentjs

I'm trying to group the array items by date.
Array list looks like this:

```
{
    title: 'title 01',
    timestamp: 1574082000000
},
{
    title: 'title 02',
    timestamp: 1574071200000
},
{
    title: 'title 03',
    timestamp: 1573974000000
},
.
.
.
```

The output should be like this:

> **November 19, 2019 ( or today )**
>
> > Title 01
> >
> > Title 02
>
> **November 18, 2019**
>
> > Title 03
>
> **Last Week**
>
> > Title 04
>
> **September**
>
> > Title ...

Frankly, I couldn't do too much but I manage to get the week names in the desired format with the following code:

```
for ( let i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++ ) {
    let timestamps = moment( transactions[i].timestamp ).startOf('week')._d
    let weeklyTime = moment( timestamps ).format( 'Do MMMM, YYYY' )

    console.log( weeklyTime )
}
```

Best,

~ Nathan.

Comment: If you did *anything*, please post it.

Comment: As you already mentioned momentjs, a good starting point is to look at the examples on their home page: https://momentjs.com Then the idea would be to check whether the date is not older than one week, then take the weekday (e.g., "moment().format('dddd')") and group by that. Otherwise, group by week or by month. But for understanding their API, the examples on their home page should get you started.

Comment: Thanks much, @PhilippClaßen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "relative time" from moment.js is what you are looking for?
`.fromNow()` method gives you a nice relative date.

```js
var transactions=[{
    title: 'title 01',
    timestamp: moment().subtract(2, 'hours') //create test date for 2 days ago
},
{
    title: 'title 02',
    timestamp: moment().subtract(2, 'hours') //create test date for 2 days ago
},
{
    title: 'title 03',
    timestamp: moment().subtract(1, 'days') //create test date for yesterday
},
{
    title: 'title 04',
    timestamp: moment().subtract(7, 'days') //create test date for last week
},
{
    title: 'title 05',
    timestamp: moment().subtract(70, 'days') //create test date for 2 months ago
}]

var transactionsSortedWithRelativeTime = transactions.sort((t1, t2) => t1.valueOf()-t2.valueOf()).map(t => ({...t, when:moment(t.timestamp).fromNow()}));

(new Set(transactionsSortedWithRelativeTime.map(t => t.when))).forEach(when => {
 console.log(when + ': ');
 transactionsSortedWithRelativeTime.filter(t => t.when == when).forEach(t => console.log('   ' + t.title))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```